# selenium javascript webdriver - unable to locate dynamic element

Tags: javascript, selenium

```
<input class="dropdown" type="text" value="Choose option" data-activates="select-123" readonly="true">

<ul id="select-123" class="content dropdown" style="width: 11px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">

<li class="please-select" style="display:none;">
<span>Choose option</span>
</li>
<li class="">
<span>city</span>
</li>
<li class="">
<span>state</span>
</li>
<li class="">
<span>country</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Once I click on "Choose option" the above code changes to:

```
<input class="dropdown active" type="text" value="Choose option" data-    activates="select-123" readonly="true">

<ul id="select-123" class="content dropdown active" style="width: 11px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: block;">

<li class="please-select" style="display:none;">
<span>Choose option</span>
</li>
<li class="">
<span>City</span>
</li>
<li class="">
<span>State</span>
</li>
<li class="">
<span>Country</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Using selenium javascript webdriver I am trying to select "State" option.

```
driver.findElement(By.css(".dropdown[value='Choose option']")).click();
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='content dropdown active']/li[3]")), 3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='content dropdown active']/li[3]")).click();
```

"Choose option" is clicked and I see the 3 options. But selenium is unable to select "State" option.

Error is:

> NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class='content dropdown active']/li[3]"}

Comment: hmm.. something is wrong with the code you provided: in xpath attributes should be preceded by `@`, but they are not in your code, however exception mentions a proper syntax with `@`, and also it mentions additional element of the xpath `li[3]`. Are you sure your code looks like what you specified?

Comment: Thanks Kiril S. Updated the code.

Comment: And what about the exception? how come you get error for `.../li[3]` when you have no such thing in your xpath? 
And actually regardless of that: I see that a style of that `<ul` explicitly sets it to invisible: `display: none;`. That should go away before you do something with an element, otherwise find will fail.

Comment: Kiril S - you are right. Updated the code.

Comment: When you click the INPUT, does the "dropdown" open?

Comment: Yes, when I click the INPUT, "dropdown" opens.

Comment: According to your HTML, the first `LI` is hidden. That would mean that you want the 2nd `LI` but with an index starting at 0, you should need `[1]`. Try `//ul[@class='content dropdown active']/li[1]`.

Comment: Error: Waiting for element to be located By(xpath, //ul[@class='content dropdown active']/li[1])

Comment: You'll have to provide more info on what is going on. We can't see the page or try anything.

Comment: try to change it to wait for parent (both class and style change), and then click on child, like this: `driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='content dropdown active' and contains(@style, 'display: block;')]")), 3000);driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='content dropdown active']/li[3]")).click();`